Why is factorial code scaling strangely with larger integers?
I wrote a Racket program to calculate factorials and ran tests to see how the runtime scaled with different values of n for n!. I was surprised to see that sometimes when scaling n, it caused little increases in the runtime but other times the difference was massive. For instance, increasing n from 10 to 100 increased the runtime by about 8x; scaling n from 1000 to 10000 increase runtime by 380x and scaling n from 10000 to 100000 increased runtime by about 42x.
I was expecting the runtime to either scale linearly or according to some type of formula.
Here's the code:
#lang racket
(define (factorial-recursive n)
  (define (fact-iter n p)
    (if (= n 1)
    1
    (fact-iter (- n 1) (* p n))))
  (fact-iter n 1)
  )

(define (factorial-iterative n)
  (define (iter c p n)
    (if (> c n)
        1
        (iter (+ c 1) (* p c) n))
    )
  (iter 1 1 n)
 )
(define (time-iterative-factorial t )
  (define x (current-inexact-milliseconds))
  (factorial-iterative t)
  (- (current-inexact-milliseconds) x)
  )

(define (time-recursive-factorial t)
  (define x (current-inexact-milliseconds))
  (factorial-recursive t)
  (- (current-inexact-milliseconds) x)
  )

(time-recursive-factorial n)

Here's a table that shows how the runtime scales with different values of n:



I suggest you try a powers of 2 series for timing values of n, n! and (2,4,8,16... or 4,16,64,256...) and then with any luck you should see the boundary(s) where it starts to run out of cache memory. There will be a nearly step change for some small change in n. The transition(s) are clearly somewhere around the n=1000 mark (at a guess one either side as first the secondary cache runs out and then the tertiary cache  does too.  L2 cache is typically about 10MB and L3 cache twice that (after that you are always waiting for main memory to deliver data).

I doubt Racket/Chez's bigints are anywhere near as highly tuned for optimum performance with different sizes of inputs as, say, libgmp's. (Though it looks like Chez 10 has changes to bignum multiplication so if you're not using the latest Racket upgrading might show some improvement)

As calibration points for speed Julia's native factorial function takes about 1s for factorial(100000), about 4s for 10^6! and 35s for 10^7! I suspect it uses a much smarter divide and conquer multiplication algorithm to multiply it up in smaller BigInt chunks. A naieve user function written in Julia to do the same as above was about 3s for 100k and I gave up waiting for 1M to complete after 5 min (on an i5-12600).

Oh yeah - use time or a benchmark library to measure runtime.

Both your functions are iterative processes, and both return 1. It is unclear why you think that one is more "recursive" than the other.

@molbdnilo Would you like to write the function that is, in your words, "more recursive than the other"?

@EgeÇalışkan The most obvious one is (define (f n) (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (f (- n 1))))). The only difference between your procedures is that one counts upwards and the other downwards. Read this about recursion and iteration.

@EgeÇalışkan The effect you missed was the growth in the number of digits.
If you modify your program to compute modulo 10000, say, then you might be able to see the behaviour you expected.

Computing n! requires n-2 multiplications, at least naïvely, if n is an integer.  But multiplication is not constant-time.  For numbers small enough that both the numbers being multiplied and the result fit in a machine word (or perhaps some small fixed number of machine words) we can pretend it is, but that's not true for n!
The simple-minded long multiplication algorithm is O(d^2) where d is the number of digits in the numbers, so O(log n) where n is the number.  There are better algorithms though.
So the time complexity of n! will be worse than linear.  If themultiplications are all logarithmic time in it will be O(log(1) + ... log(n)) which is O(log(n!)).  But how much worse depends on details of the multiplication algorithm used which may well be better than that.  It will also have a fairly obvious jump when the system stops being able to use constant-time machine arithmetic I expect.

Empirically a current Racket seems to do OK and it's much better than the simple-minded algorithm for bignum multiplication.  Given this factorial function:
(define (factorial n)
  (let floop ([i 2] [r 1])
    (if (<= i n) (floop (+ i 1) (* r i)) r)))

Here's a plot of the square root of the time (ms) it takes (measuring a single iteration: there's a limit to the amount of computer time I'm willing to spend on this!):

It's reasonably clear that the time complexity is quadratic here.  I'd not be surprised if the big step at about 4,500 is it overflowing some cache in the machine.

Thanks for the reply, I do understand it a bit clearer now. However, I'm not sure why we see such large spikes in the graph you provided. On average, there seems to be an increase (as expected) but for some values of n, the runtime decreases drastically when we look at n+1 (for instance, the huge spike at somewhere around 1100). Why is this?

@EgeÇalışkan my guess is garbage collections: since I measured only a single iteration, and the calls both have very short run-times (small numbers of ms) and are furiously consy, some of the calls will trigger the GC and end up with spuriously long times.  I haven't investigated how long GC pauses are for minor/major collections in Racket.  The way to check for this would be to average over enough calls fir each value so the GC overhead gets amortised, but I didn't want to wait for as long as that would take for 10,000 integers
